# Create unique id for each SQL record in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a query to get the MAX recordId from the table in SQL. I then put the value in an array and add 1 to the variable. I then use the variable to create the recordId in SQL. How do I increase the recordId by 1 for each loop?

```
query3 = "SELECT MAX(tbl_eInvoice_Main.RecordID) AS RecordID, " & _
            "MAX(tbl_ImportDate.toolImportId) As toolImportId FROM tbl_eInvoice_Main " & _
            "INNER JOIN tbl_ImportDate ON tbl_eInvoice_Main.ToolImportID = tbl_ImportDate.ToolImportID;"
    rs.Open query3, con, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly, adCmdText
    arr = rs.GetRows(1)
    RecordID = arr(0, 0) + 1
    ToolImportId = arr(1, 0) + 1

Worksheets("DATA").Activate
    Dim rng As Range: Set rng = Application.Range("A2:IP1000")
    Dim row As Range
    For Each row In rng.Rows

query2 = "INSERT INTO tbl_eInvoice_Main (RecordID) values (" & RecordID & ")"

con.Execute query2
    Next row
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could move your RecordID logic inside the loop like this:

```
For Each row In rng.Rows
   arr(0, 0) = arr(0, 0) + 1
   query2 = "INSERT INTO tbl_eInvoice_Main (RecordID) values (" & arr(0, 0) & ")"
   con.Execute query2
Next row
```

However, this approach won't work well if you have multiple users.  Just something to keep in mind.

Comment: So this works one time, I would have to go get the last recordID for every loop. Isn't there a way to increment for each row?

Comment: Isn't that what it's doing?  It takes your MAX(id) as the starting point and adds 1 for each row.

Comment: @ Brian Stafford I have the variable = row.Cells(<column>).value to get the value of the cell from Excel. How do I get a variable = row.Cells(<column>).Count based on if the string value is true??

Comment: I tried this; ShpCnt = row.Cells(46).CountIf(row.Cells(46), "Standard Shipment") but it does not support this method.

Comment: `row.Cells(46)` evaluates to a Range.  A Range does not have a CountIf method which is what the error message is saying.  I would suggest asking a new question to get insight from the Excel experts.